# Constructor Array

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I have a problem with my constructor concerning arrays !

In my header file i got this(simplified) :

```
    class Student
  {  
        private:
                int am;
                char name[] ;
                int grades[8];
  }
```

And in my cpp file this :

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<cstdlib> 
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;

Student::Student()
{
}

Student::Student(int am , char name,int grades)
{
    this->am=am;
    this->name=name;
    this->grades=grades;
}
```

And I am getting this error

**[Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'char*' to 'char[0]'**

P.S : I searched for answers in this site already but I am new in c++ and couldnt figure it out .

Comment: You really should be using `std::string` if you are working with strings.

Comment: Note that you have declared the parameter as `char name`. This is just a single character.

Comment: `char` is for a single character. Do your students really only have one character in their names?

Comment: An array member needs to have a size declared. `char name[]` is missing the size. You can't assign to an array, you need to use a function like `strcpy()` to copy a C-style string. But as @NathanOliver says, you should use `std::string` instead.

Comment: You also can't assign to `this->grades`. It's an array, you need to assign to specific elements. Why does the function just take one grade as an argument, not an array?

Comment: It seems like you need to reread the section on arrays in your textbook/tutorial.

Comment: Please post the entire error message. Also tell us which line causes the error.

Comment: Off topic: Looks like no one has told you about the [Member Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) yet. Very handy tool. I recommend skipping down in the link about 1/3 of the way to the Explanation section and start reading there, then go back to the section on syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's obvious what are you doing. u must define name like

```
char name[20];
```

or you should allocate memory for it in your constructor like:

```
name = new char [20];
```

if you allocate memory dynamically, don't forget to delete it

Answer (score 0):

When assigning the value of one variable to another, it is important that the types are compatible. The error message is telling you that you are attempting to make an incompatible assignment. To figure out the problem, look closely at the declarations of the variables. The class member is declared as

```
char name[] ;
```

but the parameter to the constructor is declared as

```
char name
```

Note that the first one is an array, but the second is a single character. One way to fix the current error is to change the parameter declaration to match the member field:

```
char name[]
```

However, now you will get another error because you cannot assign one array to another. Instead, you will have to copy each character one at a time. In order to avoid this and other complications, I strongly suggest that you use `std::string` instead of `char[]`.